# Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0 with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following error in my input pipeline:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot
>   batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had
>   shape [2,48,48,3] and element 1 had shape [27,48,48,3].

with this code

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator,
                                         (tf.float32, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.float32, tf.int64, tf.float32))

dataset = dataset.batch(max_buffer_size)
```

This is completely logical as the batch method tries to create a (batch_size, ?, 48, 48, 3) Tensor. However I want that it creates a [29,48,48,3] Tensor for this case. So concatenate instead of stack. Is this possible with tf.data?

I can do the concatenation in Python in the generator function, but I was wondering if this is also possible with the tf.data pipeline

Comment: So one instance (data point) has shape (48, 48, 3)? Why is your generator yielding clumps of instances in the first place?

Comment: Because they come in via a message bus into clumps of messages. Another way is indeed to yield (48,48,3) instances in the generator. However, than I need a way to make the batch size variable, because I need to send the clumps of instances together again.

Comment: I see. So the clumps are of variable size, but the number of clumps you want to concatenate is fixed? Then I might have a solution. I will post it as an answer soon.

Comment: Sorry, the solution I had in mind didn't work out.

Comment: Yes, I want to do the forward pass through the network with a larger batch. But not break the clumps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## First case: we want the output to have fixed batch size

In this case, the generator generates values of shape `[None, 48, 48, 3]` where the first dimension could be anything. We want to batch this so that the output is `[batch_size, 48, 48, 3]`. If we use directly `tf.data.Dataset.batch`, we will have an error, so we need to **unbatch** first.

To do that we can use [`tf.contrib.data.unbatch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/unbatch) like this before batching:

```py
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

---

Here is a full example where the generator yields `[1]`, `[2, 2]`, `[3, 3, 3]` and `[4, 4, 4, 4]`.

We can't batch these output values directly, so we unbatch and then batch them:

```py
def gen():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        yield [i] * i

# Create dataset from generator
# The output shape is variable: (None,)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, tf.int64, tf.TensorShape([None]))

# The issue here is that we want to batch the data
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
dataset = dataset.batch(2)

# Create iterator from dataset
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x = iterator.get_next()  # shape (None,)

sess = tf.Session()
for i in range(5):
    print(sess.run(x))
```

This will print the following output:

```
[1 2]
[2 3]
[3 3]
[4 4]
[4 4]
```

---

## Second case: we want to concatenate variable sized batches

**Update (03/30/2018):** I removed the previous answer that used sharding which slows down performance by a lot (see comments).

In this case, we want to concatenate a fixed number of batches. The issue is that these batches have variable sizes. For instance the dataset yields `[1]` and `[2, 2]` and we want to get `[1, 2, 2]` as the output.

Here a quick way to solve this is to create a new generator wrapping around the original one. The new generator will yield batched data. *(Thanks to [Guillaume](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io) for the idea)*

---

Here is a full example where the generator yields `[1]`, `[2, 2]`, `[3, 3, 3]` and `[4, 4, 4, 4]`.

```py
def gen():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        yield [i] * i

def get_batch_gen(gen, batch_size=2):
    def batch_gen():
        buff = []
        for i, x in enumerate(gen()):
            if i % batch_size == 0 and buff:
                yield np.concatenate(buff, axis=0)
                buff = []
            buff += [x]

        if buff:
            yield np.concatenate(buff, axis=0)

    return batch_gen

# Create dataset from generator
batch_size = 2
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_batch_gen(gen, batch_size),
                                         tf.int64, tf.TensorShape([None]))

# Create iterator from dataset
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x = iterator.get_next()  # shape (None,)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(2):
        print(sess.run(x))
```

This will print the following output:

```
[1 2 2]
[3 3 3 4 4 4 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point is that I do not want to split the initial clumps from the generator over multiple batches. So this could work if there is a way to make the 2 variable in this line: dataset = dataset.batch(2). For this example it should be 1 (to batch [] and [1]),  than 5 (to batch [2,2] and [3,3,3]) etc.

Comment: You always want to merge them 2 by 2?

Comment: Yes, that value will be fixed (it will be 10)

Comment: @Derk: I added this second case with a solution using sharding, zip and concatenation :)

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the effect of sharding is for performance? The whole idea is to get a faster inference pipeline

Comment: @Derk: very good question. I checked the implementation and shard will run the generation process `num_shards` times, which will be very slow... I'm not sure how to fix this then.

Comment: @Derk: updated the answer with a solution that works by wrapping the generator

Comment: Another error raise, `ValueError: Cannot unbatch an input with scalar components.`

Comment: It doesn't work anymore with the new version of tensorflow. Any updated solution? The error is still popping up.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with tensorflow 2 :

1) setting the repeat() function when creating the dataset, therefore replacing

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
```

by

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).repeat()
```

B) Passing the steps/epoch parameter to the fit method, therefore replacing

```
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

by

```
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=data[0]/BUFFER_SIZE, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```